# history.replace doesn't work in react router dom v5.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I think that I'm doing something bad. I'm trying to reload the same url (`/timetable`) when click on an item of my list, but changing the state. But when I'm on that endpoint nothing happens when I click on other `ListItem`. I mean that I'm on `/timetable` with `state = {semester: true}`, and when I click on the second item nothing changes.

I take `const history = useHistory` from `react-router-dom`.

```
<List component="div" disablePadding>
          {HorarioElements.map(({ text, icon, route, state }) => (
            <StyledListItem
              button
              key={text}
              onClick={() => {
                history.replace('/timetable', state)
              }}
            >
              <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </StyledListItem>
          ))}
</List>
```

The `HorarioElements` array is the following:

```
const HorarioElements = [
  {
    text: '1er semestre',
    icon: <Filter1Icon />,
    state: { semester: true },
  },
  {
    text: '2do semestre',
    icon: <Filter2Icon />,
    state: { semester: false },
  },
]
```

Anyone knows what is the properly way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

React Router `history.replace`'s `state` isn't the same as your app state — it's state that's present on the `history` object itself. It's rare that you'd need to use this.

To change your app state while remaining on the same page, you need [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) (for state scoped to a component or its direct children) or [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) (for state scoped to your whole app or a significant-sized subtree of your app).

Comment: So, I could take that state in the screen that renders the `/timetable` route in the following way:

`const {location} = useHistory();` `const state = location.state;` 


am I right? because this neither works.

I have a layout with the items, but I want to go to the same route with a different state dependig on what I clicked, to render different components.

Comment: No, you don't need React Router for this situation at all (unless you're using it elsewhere in the same component). You want something like `const [semester, setSemester] = useState(false)`. Then in the `onClick` callback, `setSemester(state.semester)`.